# How to log all kafka topics / events

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I am looking at how to log all Kafka topics/events.
Is there any env variable that I can run my Kafka container?
Just for the development purpose, I used

```
docker run -p 9092:9092 -e ADVERTISED_HOST=127.0.0.1 johnnypark/kafka-zookeeper
```

and when I run my python script I was able to consume and publish events

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

consumer = KafkaConsumer('other-topic')

for msg in consumer:
    print (msg)
```

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer

producer = KafkaProducer()

producer.send('other-topic', b'some_message_bytes')

producer.flush()
```

I bet there is a way to log all events, but I could not find it.

PS. I want to log all events only for development purposes. I do not want to add handlers to watch all topics, but if there is a way to consume all topics by KafkaConsumer class then will be great to know about it too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520222/how-to-subscribe-to-a-list-of-multiple-kafka-wildcard-patterns-using-kafka-pytho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex pattern to define which topics to consume from, have a look on the following example from another question

[How to subscribe to a list of multiple kafka wildcard patterns using kafka-python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520222/how-to-subscribe-to-a-list-of-multiple-kafka-wildcard-patterns-using-kafka-pytho)

```
def subscribe(self, topics=(), pattern=None, listener=None):
    """Subscribe to a list of topics, or a topic regex pattern
    Partitions will be dynamically assigned via a group coordinator.
    Topic subscriptions are not incremental: this list will replace the
    current assignment (if there is one).
```

For your  use case , you could use pattern of '.*'

And for new topics , there is configurable paramter that says how much time after new topic is created to subscribe it, check this answer as well

[Kafka pattern subscription. Rebalancing is not being triggered on new topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754865/kafka-pattern-subscription-rebalancing-is-not-being-triggered-on-new-topic)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, it work with patterns like 'customer*', but it throws an error with '*' `re.error: nothing to repeat at position 0`

Comment: Can you try something like ".*"

Comment: Works only for already used events. But for the new one, it does not :(

Comment: I think we will be not able to solve it by KafkaConsumer class because `pattern (str): Pattern to match available topics. You must provide either topics or pattern, but not both.`

Comment: So it means it will take all available topics and I think will not care about created later.

Comment: That actually do should work check this out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754865/kafka-pattern-subscription-rebalancing-is-not-being-triggered-on-new-topic

Answer (score 0):

You can consume from multiple topics using [dpkp/kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) library. As they have mentioned in there [KafkaConsumer](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer) documentation, You can simply init consumer by giving multiple topic list you want.

> classkafka.KafkaConsumer(*topics, **configs)
>
> Parameters:
> *topics (str) – optional list of topics to subscribe to. If not set, call subscribe() or assign() before consuming records

It is optional to set topics when you initialise the consumer. Later you can call `consumer.subscribe()` and give topic list or pattern to a topic list.

> **def subscribe(self, topics=(), pattern=None, listener=None):**
>
> Arguments:
>
> topics (list): List of topics for subscription.
>
> pattern (str): Pattern to match available topics. You must provide either topics or pattern, but not both.

If you don't know the topic list in kafka, you can call `consumer.topics()` to get all topics.

> **def topics(self):**
>
> Get all topics the user is authorized to view.
> This will always issue a remote call to the cluster to fetch the latest information.
>
> ```
>     Returns:
>         set: topics
> ```

Sources

- [kafka.KafkaConsumer](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer)
- [github.com/dpkp/kafka-python](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)
- [github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/kafka/consumer/group.py](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/master/kafka/consumer/group.py)

Comment: Hmm, not bad. But I am looking for something more dynamic, cause once I will define the list of topics then I will be not able to subscribe to new ones.

Comment: Just an idea. I haven't experience on this.
you have to restart consumer for that. Write separate thread running in background and get topic list and compare with previous. if there is new topics, restart consumer with new list.